# Bipartite Graph: Show that if $\deg(V_0)=3$, then we may $\Delta +1$ edge colour such a graph $G$.

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

Suppose that every odd cycle in a graph $G$ contains some specific vertex 
$V_0$

a) Give an example that shows that $\chi^E(G)$ may be larger than $\Delta$

b) Show that if $\deg(V_0)=3$, then we may $\Delta +1$ edge colour such a graph $G$.

$\chi^E(G)$ is the edge chromatic number which is the minimum # colors needed to edge color G.

Comment: What is X^E(G) ?

Comment: And why does bipartiteness occur only in the title, not in the actual problem?

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen In fact if $G$ is bipartite it cant have any odd cycles

Comment: @Amr I'm guessing this is supposed to be $\chi'(G)$, the edge colouring number.  Part b) seems a bit funny as it's always true that $\chi'(G) \le \Delta+1$, but the two parts certainly would go well together.

Comment: @ErickWong That's another one !

Answer (score 1):

I assume that $\Delta$ is the maximal degree and that $\chi^E(G)$ is the edge-chromatic number (minimal number of coulours for an edge-colouring).

a) The triangle graph has $\Delta=2$, but $\chi^E(G)=3$ (and any vertex can play the role of $V_0$)

b) If we remove two of the edges $V_0A$, $V_0B$ incident with $V_0$, the graph becomes bipartite (because there are no odd cycles). A bipartite graph has $\chi^E(G')=\Delta(G')\le \Delta(G)$. Construct a valid colouring for $G$ from this (you may need to swap a few colours)